# QLineEdit is not editable but I want it to be

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit

I'm trying to make a node based interface, and I want to make a Value node with a `QLineEdit` to be editable and I want the user to be able to move the node, but It's not working.

The node is displayed and is movable but the `QLineEdit` is not editable.

Here's a minimal reproducible example, the problem: the user can't interact with the widgets inside the graphic element.

```
class TestLineEdit(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, width: float, height: float, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.groupBox = QGroupBox("Contact Details")
        self.numberLabel = QLabel("Telephone number")
        self.numberEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.layout = QFormLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.layout.addRow(self.numberLabel, self.numberEdit)

        self.proxy_widget = QGraphicsProxyWidget(self)
        self.proxy_widget.setWidget(self.groupBox)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(self.rect())

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        pass

test_line_edit: TestLineEdit = TestLineEdit(100, 100)
test_group = QGraphicsItemGroup()
test_group.addToGroup(test_line_edit)
test_group.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, enabled=True)
scene.addItem(test_group)
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to a proper [mre] and within a single code block.

Comment: I added a proper minimal reproducible example.

Comment: The `ItemIsMovable` completely prevents the child items to get their events, so the line edit will never get any mouse focus. It also makes no sense to use a QGraphicsRectItem as a container if it's completely **empty** (and you're not even painting it). Besides, your code is not an acceptable [mre]: nobody could copy, paste and run it without making **lots** of editing that could possibly make the problem invalid. Please take your time and create an acceptable MRE, we need to focus on the problem, without being distracted (or annoyed, then possibly giving up) by *trying* to reproduce it.